# Using ORDER and GROUP with MySQL to get the highest number for each GROUP

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have made a simple auction section on my site, and I would like to display the user's current high bid on their My Bids page.  I have a table that holds each unique bid that has the unique auction_id.  My current query is as follows, but this only orders the groups instead of ordering what is inside the groups as well.  I only want the highest value in each group.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAuctionBids 
WHERE username = '$username' 
GROUP BY auction_id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(bid), * 
FROM tblAuctionBids 
WHERE username='$username' 
GROUP BY auction_id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```